# MySQL does not start on startup

Tags: macos, startup, system-settings, mysql

In the System Preferences panel, I have the MySQL there.

[image]

[image]

I chose it to start up every time my Mac starts up, however this doesn't work, I have restarted MySQL many times, but it will not start up at all - which I require to start up *manually*.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you search for any hints in /var/log already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting MySQL server automatically actually means executing the `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld` dæmon on startup. If MySQL won't do it for you, it's easy enough to add the necessary instructions yourself.

For this, we'll add a launchd job descriptor to the `/Library/LaunchDaemons` folder. The procedure is very well described in [this Mac OS X Hints article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080128103022907).

---

*Note: I would have liked to copy and edit it here, since it adds some details that are unnecessary in this case, but I couldn't find license information about Mac OS X Hints' content, so I'll simply link.*

Answer (score 1):

There should also be logs in /usr/local/mysql/data. You'll have to "sudo su" from a Terminal session in order to see that directory. Check for any errors being reported in a filed named like this: "Your-computer-name.local.err"

Report back whatever you see that doesn't make sense.

You can also check out the startup script to make sure there are no errors. Find that here: /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MYSQLCOM

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any type of logs in the `/usr/local/mysql/data` directory. The file/directory does not exist in `/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MYSQLCOM`.

Answer (score 1):

Use terminal and paste this snippet:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Comment: You don't have to be root to use sudo, being an admin user is enough.